# fullcalendar weekly view displays squashed in Chrome

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using an old installation of 1.5.3 in a bootstrap-based system.
I am loading a page via ajax, that contains a `fullcalendar` instance - in weekly view.

This is only the case in Chrome - looks find in Firefox/Explorer.

Note: the ajax page that I bring in does NOT have `<!DOCTYPE....` header tags - rather, its just plain INNER HTML code - along with the relevant css/js for fullcalendar

this is my basic code:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        theme: true,
        weekends: false,
        weekendDays: [5,6],
        header: {
            left: '',
            center: '',
            right: ''
        },
        allDaySlot : false,
        firstHour: 8,
        minTime: 8,
        maxTime: 23,
        columnFormat: {week: 'ddd'}, 
        editable: false,
        events: [
            .....

        ]
    });
```

Chrome: example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6tei.png

Firefox example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bM5Uy.jpg

Comment: what versions of Chrome / Firefox? I see you've got some custom CSS for fullCalendar. Remove that and see if it works. It's more likely to be the culprit than any browser bug.

Comment: Thank you - turned out there was a separate script running on the page, that was throwing a 500 error - and that was causing rhe cal not to load properly.